# ./my_script: line 21: =: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm getting this error when running this simple shell script:

```
previous_run=$(cat last_completed.txt)
for file in /Users/everardobarriga/testimg
do
   b=$(ls -l "$file"|awk '{print $6$7$8}')
   if [ "$previous_run" <= "$b" ]
     then
       echo $'yes'
   fi
done
date +"%h%d%H:%M"> last_completed.txt
```

It seems that on the line where I am comparing the previous run and b, it's not really comparing them. I am totally new to shell scripting so I'm not sure what's going on. Sometimes it compares them sometimes it doesn't.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the error?  All I see is code...

Comment: I don't see a line 21. I only count 10.

Comment: @fvrghl, "No such file or directory". It's written in the title.

Comment: I think the question is, is there any way to compare two strings for greater than or less than in a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "<=" as a less-than-or-equal comparator. The syntax you specified is attempting to redirect stdin from a file called '=' (which doesn't exist). Refer to "man test" and you'll see a variety of available comparison options. It looks like you want "-le" in this case:

```
if [ "$previous_run" -le "$b" ]; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

Comment: Yes, it's written in the title, and the error is in line 5, I think -le only compares integers and what I am comparing I think are strings is there a special way of comparing strings?

Answer (score 0):

To sort string lexicographically you can use `<` or `>` inside test. However the less or greater than symbol needs to be in quotes so the shell doesn't interpret them as redirection.

Example

```
if [ "str1" '<' "str2" ]; then
    echo "str1 is before str2"
else
    echo "str1 is after str2"
fi
```

Comment: As I'm not really sure what your trying to do I'm not sure this will get you the result you expect.